# How to run my node.js application on when my raspberry pi boots through rc.local?

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run my node.js application when my raspberry pi boots.

I would like the pi to run the following command on boot:

`node bot.js`

I first tried adding the following line to `rc.local`:

`node /PPBot/bot.js < /dev/null &`

Since that didn't work I tried adding the full path:

`node /home/pi/PPBot/bot.js < /dev/null &`

This still doesn't work and I currently don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect the ouput of your script into `/dev/null` ? Because if so, your "less than sign" is the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `bot.js` access any files from the current directory? If yes, you should `cd` to the directory first.

This is what should be in your `/etc/rc.local` file:

```
cd /home/pi/PPBot
node bot.js > /dev/null &
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that. However the bot is still not running on boot. The weird thing is that it worked before, but after installing nvm as my node version manager it doesn't work anymore.